# Simplifying easy expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\frac{u-2}{u^{1/2}}=u^{1/2}-2u^{-1/2}$

How does this work?

I know that it adds up, but I'm just not sure about the mechanics at play.

Are there any similar cases? Thank you.

Comment: Multiply by $u^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a matter of splitting the fraction into a difference of two fractions, each of which is then simplified using the laws of exponents:

$$\frac{u-2}{u^{1/2}}=\frac{u}{u^{1/2}}-\frac2{u^{1/2}}=u^1\cdot u^{-1/2}-2\cdot u^{-1/2}=u^{1-\frac12}-2u^{-1/2}=u^{1/2}-2u^{-1/2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it. I'm going to change the equation slightly. You can try it again with your own equation.

Let's look for the real-number solutions to
$$\frac{u-3}{u^{3/8}}=u^{5/8}-3u^{-3/8}.$$
Notice this equation
is implicitly assuming $u>0$, because otherwise $u^{-3/8}$ wouldn't make sense.

On the left, we have $u^{3/8}$ in the denominator, and on the right, all the $u$s have exponents that are also eighths. Therefore it would make sense to multiply both sides by $u^{3/8}$ so that there won't be a fraction, and since it wouldn't
make the exponents on the right any "more complicated" we expect this will greatly simplify
the equation.

The left hand side becomes
$$ u^{3/8} \frac{u-3}{u^{3/8}},$$ which simplifies to $u-3$ because the $u^{3/8}$ cancel due to $u^{3/8} \div u^{3/8}=1$. On the right hand side we have 
$u^{3/8}(u^{5/8} - 3u^{-3/8})$. Don't forget the parentheses, which are needed to ensure that you're multiplying the *entire* right hand side by $u^{3/8}$. Expand $u^{3/8}(u^{5/8} - 2u^{-3/8})$ to $u^{3/8} u^{5/8} - u^{3/8} 3u^{-3/8}$. Now use the exponent rules to get $u^{3/8 + 5/8} - 3 u ^{3/8 - 3/8}$. Simplifying the exponents, $u^1 - 3u^0$ which is more natural to write as $u-3$ since $u^1=u$ and $u^0=1$. All these simplifications didn't change the values of the expression, so both sides are still equal to one another.  We've simplified $$\frac{u-3}{u^{3/8}}=u^{5/8}-3u^{-3/8}$$ down to
$$u-3 = u-3.$$
Now adding $3$ to both sides we get $u=u$.

Has something gone wrong? "$u=u$"? aren't we supposed to get $u=$ some number? What's happened is that the "information" in our original equation wasn't enough to specify that $u$ has to be one particular number. The original equation is true for all values of $u$ for which all the expressions in the equation make sense. But, remembering that the original equation only made sense when $u>0$, we can't say that $u$ can be *any* number; rather, the answer is that 
$$\frac{u-3}{u^{3/8}}=u^{5/8}-3u^{-3/8}$$
is true for any $u>0$. In other words the solution set is all real numbers $u$ such that $u>0$.

Another method would be to start with the original equation 
$$\frac{u-3}{u^{3/8}}=u^{5/8}-3u^{-3/8}$$
and apply the exponent rules immediately instead of clearing the denominator. The right hand-side can't be simplified with exponent rules, but the left hand side can be written
$ u^{-3/8}(u - 3)$. Now some students will find this tricky because we have to apply two facts about simplifying exponents, but use them backwards from how we usually use them to make expressions simpler. First, when we see $u$, we can always think of that as $u^1$. Secondly, when we see a lone number like $3$, we can always think of that as $3u^0$ because $u^0=1$ so that $3=3\times1 = 3u^0$. Thus our expression $u^{-3/8}(u - 3)$ can be written 
$u^{-3/8}(u^1 - 3u^0)$, and expanding and using exponent rules we get $u^{-3/8 + 1} - 3u^{-3/8+0}$. Of course, simplifying the exponents we get $u^{5/8} - 3u^{-3/8}$. So this is our new left-hand side.
So we have simplified our original equation 
$$\frac{u-3}{u^{3/8}}=u^{5/8}-3u^{-3/8}$$
to the equation 
$$u^{5/8}-3u^{-3/8}=u^{5/8}-3u^{-3/8}.$$
Here, if you're attentive, you'll notice both sides are the exact same expression. So we recognize this equation is an "identity", it holds for all the $u$ for which the expressions make sense. As before, we see that our original equation (and in this case our simplified equation also) only makes sense when $u>0$. The equation is therefore true for all $u>0$, the same answer as before.

We could also keep going if you didn't notice (it won't hurt though on a test it might waste time), adding $3u^{3/8}$ to both sides to get $u^{5/8}=u^{5/8}$. But at this point I think it's obvious to most people that both sides are the same, so the reasoning would proceed as above. You need to be careful here though because while $0$ solves $u^{5/8}=u^{5/8}$, it will not solve our original equation because it had a division and negative exponents.

That's the detailed explanation of all the mechanics involved in solving the euquation. As you get more skilled with the techniques (or if you already are skilled), you will be able to do many of these steps "in your head" without explicitly writing them all out.

Finally, I'd like to add that above when I said "the right hand can't be simplified by exponent rules" that was a little white lie. The right hand side can be simplified using exponent rules by a sneaky clever trick, but it's not as obvious as simplifying the left hand side. For $u^{5/8} = u^{5/8 +3/8 - 3/8} = u^{1 - 3/8} = uu^{-3/8}$ so the right hand side can be *factored* by $u^{5/8} - 3u^{-3/8}$ becoming $u u^{-3/8} - 3u^{-3/8}$ and then factoring out $u^{-3/8}$ to get $u^{-3/8} (u -3)$ at which point your new right hand side is identical to your left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar case.

$$\frac{121-2}{\sqrt{121}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{121}}(121-2)=\frac{121}{\sqrt{121}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{121}}=\frac{\sqrt{121}\sqrt{121}}{\sqrt{121}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{121}}=\sqrt{121}-2\frac{1}{\sqrt{121}},$$
and we have $\sqrt{121}=(121)^{1/2}$ so
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{121}}=\frac{1}{(121)^{1/2}}=(121)^{-1/2},$$
so we have
$$\frac{121-2}{\sqrt{121}}=(121)^{1/2}-2(121)^{-1/2}.$$

Your example just recognises that there is nothing special about $121$ here --- just that it is strictly bigger than zero.